# Nuxt 3: Nested dynamic routes not prerendering as expected

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vercel, nuxt3

I'm working on a Nuxt 3 project with the goal of having every page prerendered at build time, except for specific dynamic routes like my shop and products pages, which should always be dynamic. I'm encountering an issue where nested dynamic routes aren't being prerendered as intended. While my `projects/index.vue` works fine, the dynamically queried `projects/[slug].vue` aren't being prerendered. The data is always pulled in fresh on these pages.

Here's my current `routeRules` setup inside my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
routeRules: {
    '/**': { prerender: true },
    '/projects': { prerender: true },
    '/projects/**': { prerender: true },
    '/shop': { isr: false },
    '/shop/**': { isr: false },
    '/shop/products/**': { isr: false },
}
```

With this setup, while top-level routes are prerendered as intended (included the /projects route), the nested dynamic routes under `/projects/**` aren't. I'm deploying on Vercel and wondering if this might be influencing the behavior.

Any advice on ensuring these nested routes are prerendered as intended would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!